# How to run a command with alias?

Tags: raspbian

I'm very new to Linux environment and I just got myself a Pi to play with it. Recently I found this command to check my Pi's temperature which is `/opt/vc/bin/vcgencmd measure_temp`

Is it possible to save that command somewhere with a shortcut or an alias? So that I could just type in like `checktemp` and it would run the command.

Ignore me if I'm asking a nonsense question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the `alias` command. To make it persistent, you'll have to modify the `~/.bash_aliases` file.

1. Open the `~/.bash_aliases` file with your favorite editor (`nano`, `vim`, ...)

   ```
   $ nano ~/.bash_aliases
   ```
2. Add to the end of the file the following line

   ```
   alias checktemp='/opt/vc/bin/vcgencmd measure_temp'
   ```

   , where `checktemp` is the command you want to use.
3. Exit your bash session:

   ```
   $ exit
   ```

   Then log in.
4. You are ready to use your brand new command:

   ```
   $ checktemp
   temp=48.7'C
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Don't need to exit bash, just reload your profile.

From anywhere:
$ . ~/.profile

From your home dir:
$ . .profile

Answer (score 0):

What they did above was good. FYI .bash_aliases is not there by default in new Raspian OS. If you are using a non-root user to run these change the above that Morgan Courbet Said to this:

```
alias checktemp='sudo /opt/vc/bin/vcgencmd measure_temp'
```

Then reload like the others said like this:

```
. ~/.bash_aliases
```

So you can add a `.bash_aliases` and still work. I think its better than putting into another file since you usually want many aliases to make it easier. Also, for the `sudo` command to work, you need to have you user in `visudo` like this.

```
visudo

anthony ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

I hope this helps clarify some.

Answer (score 0):

I just added this to my .bashrc

sudo nano .bashrc

Went down to the bottom of the fil (CTRL-V)

alias temp='/opt/vc/bin/vcgencmd measure_temp'

(CTRL-O)
(CTRL-X)

sudo reboot

now I just type temp and it displays it.

I tried the .bash_aliases but couldn't seem to get it to work, but I am new to this so :)

Answer (score 0):

To save an alias, you can use `.bashrc` or `.bash_aliases`, although on other distributions other than Raspbian `.bashaliases` may not be available. Here's how to make the alias last:

First, open `.bashrc` or `.bash_aliases`, like this:

```sh
nano ~/.bashrc
```

Go to the end of file and add your alias (also remember that there must be no space before and after the equal "=" sign, to prevent errors).

```sh
alias checktemp='sudo /opt/vc/bin/vcgencmd measure_temp'
```

Then save the file. If you used `.bashrc`, then run:

```sh
source .bashrc
```

Or instead you can reboot the system.

After that, the alias should work fine.

Comment: You wrote: "*.bash_aliases may not be available in every distribution*", but on Raspbian it is, so no need to mention it. You can also use `.bash_aliases` and I would prefer it. After modifying `.bashrc` it is really not needed to reboot the whole computer. Logout and login or even better just execute `source .bashrc`.

Answer (score -2):

This article explains the command you are looking for: [alias command](http://linux-bible.com/alias-command/)

Comment: Welcome to the Rapsberry PI StackExchange.  Generally speaking, link only answers are against best practices.  While it's important to cite sources, a better answer would include at least a high level summary of the links content and an example.  Links have a tendency to "rot".